# Constant field at compiletime

Tags: c#, constants, code-analysis, fxcop

Is there any way to distinguish a non-constant field and a constant field" at compile time in c#?

I am currently developing c# Code Analysis (FxCop) rules to check the developers' code for inconsistency in naming.

What I have been looking for is a way to target only constant fields. But how are they declared when compiled? Is there like a flag (I have been looking into "HasDefault", but this didn't give me much information).

I am using the FxCop-API (FxCopSdk.dll & Microsoft.Cci.dll). No Reflection is used.

Summing up: How can I distinguish a non-constant field from a constant field with Code Analysis(FxCop), and how can I target the constant.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - are you trying to spot the difference between `const int x = 10;` and `static readonly int x = 10;` using reflection?

Comment: No, I am not sure if you are familiar with Code Analysis (formerly known as FxCop) in Visual Studio. This is a mechanism that checks your compiled code against all sorts of rules such as incorrect naming. For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx. What I want to know, is how I can target constants using this mechanism.

Comment: Sounds more appropriate for StyleCop to me, which already does what you want I think. The naming of a private variable/constant needn't be preserved in the compiled assembly.

Comment: StyleCop does indeed do this, but I have been ordered to implement this using FxCop because these rules are less simple to ignore by the developers. Also this mechanism can stop the program from compiling, "forcing" the developer to use the defined standards.

Comment: @MatthijsL: I'm aware of the general idea, but not exactly what API you use to develop new rules.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Using the FxCop API, no Reflection. I have added this in the original question as well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researchign further into the FxCop SDK you mentioned, i foudn a field, IsLiteral, which basically means a member which value is specified at compile time.

Would this work for you?

E.g

```
    public class ClassFieldNamePrefixes : BaseIntrospectionRule
    {
        public ClassFieldNamePrefixes() :
            base("ClassFieldNamePrefixes", "TutorialRules.TutorialRules",
                typeof (ClassFieldNamePrefixes).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
        {
            if (!(member.DeclaringType is ClassNode))
                return this.Problems;

            Field fld = member as Field;
            if (fld == null)
                return this.Problems;

            if (fld.IsLiteral && 
                fld.IsStatic && 
                field.Flags.HasFlag(FieldFlags.HasDefault))
            {
            ....
            }

            return this.Problems;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to target these type modifiers. Do you know how I could target them?

Comment: I had just discovered the same, with the addition of one common flag all constant fields had. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What about using IsStatic with IsLiteral?

Comment: as a constant keyword makes a member static?

Comment: Yes, you could add that as well. But I would add the HasDefault flag as well. Could you add it so I can accept your answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

If I compile some assembly that contains this class

```
namespace Foo
{
    public static class Bar
    {
        public int Pointless()
        {
            const int Whatever = 1;
            return Whatever;  
        }
    }
}
```

`Whatever` will not be accesible outside the class. I think, even using reflection. In fact, it may be simplified away in the IL (this is conjecture.)

The name of `Whatever` is purely a style issue and has no effect on the compiled assembly. If it were a `public` field, e.g.

```
namespace Foo
{
    public static class Bar
    {
        public const int Whatever = 1;
    }
}
```

then the name could be analysed by Code Analysis.

---

Given that public non-constant fields will already be flagged by

> [CA1051: Do not declare visible instance fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182141.aspx)
>
> [CA2211: Non-constant fields should not be visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182353.aspx)

perhaps you don't actually need to distinguish at all.

Comment: This is actually what I am trying to target, fields. I should have been clearer in my questioning, sorry! In fact this does change the entire question, really sorry!

Comment: Where as this is good information, it still does not answer my question as to being able to actually target constant fields.

Comment: @MatthijsL, only thing I can think of is decompiling `NonConstantFieldsShouldNotBeVisible` and seeing how the author did it. I can't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: I did this indeed, decompiling the rule and seeing what's what. It uses (as answered) field.IsLiteral. Also there is very close to none documentation on Code Analysis(FxCop), which can be a real buggar when working on such rules.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a somewhat dirty way of targeting constants.

Using the following will target them (but may give false-positives):

```
Field field = member as Field;

if (field == null) 
    return null;
if (field.Flags.HasFlag(FieldFlags.HasDefault) && field.IsLiteral && Field.IsStatic)
{
  // Your code here.
}
```